# Using JSON data with Angular's $resource

Tags: json, angularjs

I faced two different ways of saving data from $resource in Angular.
I translated them to my needs and here how they looks:

1:

```
    $scope.images = [ ];
    $scope.images = resService.query();
```

2:

```
    var slider = this;
    slider.images = [ ];
    $scope.images  = resService.query();
```

And the main resource is:

```
app.service('resService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(API + 'slides.json');
});
```

Here is what I get in response for both cases:

1:

```
[$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]
    0: Resource
    1: Resource
    ...
    6: Resource
    $promise: Promise
    $resolved: true
    length: 7
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

2:

```
Constructor {images: Array[0]}
images: Array[7]
    0: Resource
    1: Resource
    ...
    6: Resource
    $promise: Promise
    $resolved: true
    length: 7
    __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
```

I Assume first way is not the best one, since promise isn't resolved, though it works fine with $scope. 
So, the question is: in which way $resource should be used and why?
Best regards.

Comment: These lines aren't needed:     `slider.images = [ ];` The `resService.query();` does the same in both cases. The promises are resolved in an asyncronous way, so the related variables will be updated when the data arrives.

Comment: @Lajos Veres, shouldn't an empty array be initialised before data returns, since page is rendered before that happens?

Comment: the following lines (resService.query()) do this initialisation automatically. So it is not needed previously.